# Convert domain name to URL string

Tags: vb.net, url

How do I convert a string containing just a domain name to a fully qualified URL?

Example:

- `google.com` should be `http://www.google.com`
- `https://google.com` should stay as-is

Comment: Do you want to create a URL redirect?

Comment: No. I just wanted it to add `http://www.` if `https://` or `http://` isn't already there.

Comment: What does your current code look like/what have you already tried?

Comment: I don't know _what_ to try.

Comment: @snuggles08 If you haven't yet tried anything, this is not the best place to start your attempt. Although you have been a user for some time, you appear to have difficulty asking good questions. I recommend you read [the entire Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and head back when you have a specific, programming-related question.

Comment: If you just want to add `http://www.` when `https` or `http` isn't there. This can be done with a simple call to Contains and then append the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim str As String = "google.com" 'assign this to whatever your real url is....
    If str.IndexOf("http://") <0 And str.IndexOf("https://") <0 Then
        str = "http://www." & str
    End If
```

Do note, this will work fine for URL's, as it's impossible for that pattern to appear twice in a url, however with other strings, you should be careful with this method...

```
    Dim str As String = "google.com" 'assign this to whatever your real url is....
    If str.Contains("http://") = false And str.Contains("https://") = false Then
        str = "http://www." & str
    End If
```

another way to do it, same potential pitfall with other strings, though.

```
    Dim str As String = "google.com" 'assign this to whatever your real url is....
    If str.StartsWith("http://") = False And str.StartsWith("https://") = False Then
        str = "http://www." & str
    End If
```

yet another way...this is probably the safest way to do it.

Comment: Right you are.  Oversight on my part, modified accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I used this function:

```
Private Function MakeURL(url As String)
    If url.StartsWith("http://") = True Or url.StartsWith("https://") = True Then
        Return New Uri(url)
    Else
        Dim StrResult As String = url
        StrResult = "http://www." & StrResult
        Debug.Print(StrResult)
        Return New Uri(StrResult)
    End If
End Function
```